# Rails text formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that allows users to type in text. I wanted to know how do I make that text formatted?

For example when a user makes a new paragraph in the text input field, I want those gaps to show when I render the text to be displayed but, at the moment it is just a big chunk of text with no spaces.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use simple_format [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html) doc. m sure it will work,

here how i use it in my project;

```
= simple_format my_text
```

where

```
my_text = "foo bar
Testing helloworold foo bar
Testing helloworld foo bar
Testing helloworld foo bar
Testing helloworld foo bar
Testing helloworld foo bar
"
```

This will get displayed with enters you have given in the text and will render all the spaces also.

Answer (score 7):

When a user use `<Enter>` character in a text input (or text area), it will be correctly displayed into it.

Rails doen't make particular traitment with this character. Then, when you render it, you create some HTML like `<%= my_text %>`. But `<Enter>` characters are not rendered in HTML.

You can use simple_format to do that: it replace all the `\n` (enter caracters) with some `<br/>`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format